# Opposite ticklabel positions using middle axes

Tags: pgfplots, ticks

I need to change the position of my ticklabels because they are not readable:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,% axis y line=middle,
  xtick = {-1-sqrt(6), -1+sqrt(6)},
  xticklabels = {$-1-\sqrt{6}$, $-1+\sqrt{6}$},
  ytick = {-5-2*sqrt(6)},
  yticklabels = {$-5-2\sqrt{6}$},
  xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $f(x)$, no markers, ]

  \addplot+[thick, domain=-9:7,samples=80] {((x-1)*(x-2))/(x+1)};

  \draw[<->,red] (axis cs:{-1-sqrt(6)},{-5-2*sqrt(6)}) +(axis direction cs:-1,0) --++(axis direction cs:1,0);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**I would like to have xticklabels above and yticklabels at the right of their axes.**

I tried using the `pos` key with no success.
Then I used `right` and `above` at ticklabels style. It works, but the position are modified relatively to the original tick anchor: as a result, labels are too close from the ticks:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,% axis y line=middle,
  xtick = {-1-sqrt(6), -1+sqrt(6)},
%   xticklabel pos = top, % no effect
  xticklabel style={above},
  xticklabels = {$-1-\sqrt{6}$, $-1+\sqrt{6}$},
  ytick = {-5-2*sqrt(6)},
  yticklabels = {$-5-2\sqrt{6}$},
%   yticklabel pos = right, % no effect
  yticklabel style={right},
  xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $f(x)$, no markers, ]

  \addplot+[thick, domain=-9:7,samples=80] {((x-1)*(x-2))/(x+1)};

  \draw[<->,red] (axis cs:{-1-sqrt(6)},{-5-2*sqrt(6)}) +(axis direction cs:-1,0) --++(axis direction cs:1,0);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What is the proper way to achieve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add `xshift` and `yshift` to the styles.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} %<-maybe add
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,% axis y line=middle,
  xtick = {-1-sqrt(6), -1+sqrt(6)},
  xticklabel style={above,yshift=0.5ex},
  xticklabels = {$-1-\sqrt{6}$, $-1+\sqrt{6}$},
  ytick = {-5-2*sqrt(6)},
  yticklabels = {$-5-2\sqrt{6}$},
  yticklabel style={right,xshift=0.5ex},
  xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $f(x)$, no markers, ]

  \addplot+[thick, domain=-9:7,samples=80] {((x-1)*(x-2))/(x+1)};

  \draw[<->,red] (axis cs:{-1-sqrt(6)},{-5-2*sqrt(6)}) +(axis direction cs:-1,0) --++(axis direction cs:1,0);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd also use `compat=1.16` and `unbounded coords=jump`. And, most importantly with `xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length}` as [suggested by Stefan Pinnow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524221/opposite-ticklabel-positions-using-middle-axes/524238?noredirect=1#comment1326225_524238).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} %<- added
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,% axis y line=middle,
  xtick = {-1-sqrt(6), -1+sqrt(6)},
  xticklabel style={above,yshift=0.5ex},
  xticklabels = {$-1-\sqrt{6}$, $-1+\sqrt{6}$},
  ytick = {-5-2*sqrt(6)},
  yticklabels = {$-5-2\sqrt{6}$},
  yticklabel style={right,xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length}},
  xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $f(x)$, no markers, 
  unbounded coords=jump]

  \addplot+[thick, domain=-9:7,samples=81,smooth] {((x-1)*(x-2))/(x+1)};

  \draw[<->,red] (axis cs:{-1-sqrt(6)},{-5-2*sqrt(6)}) +(axis direction cs:-1,0) --++(axis direction cs:1,0);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've thought to xshift but I was looking for something more "elegant" (without being obliged to guess which length is good).

Comment: And what the parameter does 'compat' changes? I don't understand what command it modifies here.

Comment: I don't agree that `right` doesn't make sense. As is written in the [manual (at the definition of `ticklabel pos` in section 4.15.2 on page 343 (v1.16))](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=343) this is just an alias for `upper`. It *could* be a bug, but I am not sure about it because of the statement at the same place that "This option is only useful for boxed axes -- keep it to `default` for non-boxed figures.".

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks. I delete the comment. Yet I (also) do not see a bug here.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, a minor improvement to your answer: Instead of stating *absolute* `shift` values, state `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length}` ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome ;)